# how to do put curl to java by invoking http methods

Tags: java, curl

I am wondering how I can write a PUT curl to java to do this for me by invoking HTTP methods, Apache HttpClient.

```
curl -X PUT username:passowrd http://localhost:80/api/cleint_id/include/id
```

I can GET curl easily in java so it shows all the ids and client-is but I stuck with PUT curl to include id to client_id. Any idea or similar work that I can inspire from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you don't use HttpPut http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPut.html, since you are working with HttpClient?

Apache HttpComponents provides an example for client authentication. See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java

Adjust it with HttpPut and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache HTTPClient, see http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x
and use NameValuePair for authentication.

like this

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
PostMethod httppost = new PostMethod('your url');
NameValuePair[] data = [new NameValuePair("email", username),new NameValuePair("password",   password)];
httppost.setRequestBody(data)
httpclient.executeMethod(httppost);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but the data I want to send via put is not valuePair( array) its jsonObject

Comment: HttpClient doesn't know anything about JSON, in this case you yourself have to create a json structure in form of string or if u already have an json object you can convert it inot a string and can send it as value. On the server side you can take that string and parse it and use it as you need. This might not be the most easiest solution but i can think of any thing else right now